List of protobuf messages to JSON array
I have a protobuf message definition like this:
message MyThing {
  string foo = 1;
  int32 bar = 2;
}

And a Java/Kotlin API that returns a List<MyThing>
I need to format this as a JSON string, as follows:
[
    {
      "foo": "value1",
      "bar": 1,
    },
    {
      "foo": "value2",
      "bar": 2,
    },
    {
      "foo": "value3",
      "bar": 3,
    }
]

I know I can use JsonFormat to convert protobuf to JSON, however that only operates on a single message. So where I'm having difficulty is how to convert a list of messages to a properly formatted JSON array as shown in the example above without resorting to using string manipulation to manually format it myself.
I have briefly looked at using the Gson library but I'm not sure if this is the right approach.
Follow-up
I have a slightly unsatisfying solution (in Kotlin):
val list = ... // Some List<MyThing>
val gson = GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create()
val jsonPrinter = JsonFormat.printer().preservingProtoFieldNames()
val jsonList = list.map { thing -> jsonPrinter.print(thing) }
val jsonElement = JsonParser.parseString(jsonList.toString())
val result = gson.toJson(jsonElement)

This gets me exactly what I need, though it relies on the toString() method of List to produce valid JSON. Which based on the documentation, it will.

I'm not a Java developer but familiar with protobufs.
I Assume you're using proto3 though I think it makes no difference in this case.
You've (at least) two options:

repeated (recommended)
Protobuf Well-Known Types `ListValue'

repeated
There's a repeated field (!) label but this can only be specified on a field which must be part of a(nother) message, i.e.:
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "...";

message MyThing {
  string foo = 1;
  int32 bar = 2;
}

// X is a message that defines a 'list' field of type '[]MyThing'
message X {
  repeated MyThing list = 1;
}

A consequence of this is that your JSON can only be (un)marshaled to/from Protobuf if it forms part of a containing JSON object, e.g.:
{
  "list": [
    {
      "foo": "foo",
      "bar": 1
    },
    {
      "foo": "foo",
      "bar": 2
    }
  ]
}


NOTE This JSON is valid as it omits the trailing commas

However, an advantage of this approach is that your list retains its []MyThing type.
ListValue
Most languages provide implementations for Well-Known Types and I assume Java does too.
You can unmarshal your JSON directly into ListValue.
However (!!):

loss of the stricter type of []MyThing
complexity from having to switch of Value types

And, you will still need a(nother) message to capture the ListValue:
syntax = "proto3";

option java_package = "...";

import "google/protobuf/struct.proto";

message MyThing {
  string foo = 1;
  int32 bar = 2;
}

// Y is a message that defines a 'list' field of type JSON array
message Y {
  google.protobuf.ListValue list = 1;
}

